Проблема с перемещением курсора в консоли C#
Я разрабатываю консольное приложение на C#, которое позволяет редактировать многострочный текст в консоли. У меня возникла проблема с обработкой клавиш PageUp, PageDown, LeftArrow и RightArrow для перемещения курсора по тексту.
Я использую следующий код для обработки клавиш LeftArrow и RightArrow:
case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
    if (cursorLeft > 0)
    {
        cursorLeft--;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);
    }
    break;

case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
    if (cursorLeft < input.Length)
    {
        cursorLeft++;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);
    }
    break;

И для клавиш PageUp и PageDown:
case ConsoleKey.PageUp:
    if (cursorTop > 0)
    {
        cursorTop--;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);
    }
    break;

case ConsoleKey.PageDown:
    if (cursorTop < input.Split('\n').Length - 1)
    {
        cursorTop++;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);
    }
    break;

При нажатии клавиш PageUp и PageDown в текущую строку консоли вставляется пустой символ.
При нажатии клавиш LeftArrow и RightArrow курсор всегда перемещается на вторую строку консоли в 0 позицию.
Подозреваю, что проблема связана с тем, что положение курсора заранее определено в переменных cursorTop и cursorLeft. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить эти проблемы.
Ниже представлен полный код метода обрабатывающего обработку клавиш:
 static string ReadMultilineInput()
 {
     string input = string.Empty;
     bool isEditing = true;
     int cursorLeft = 0;
     int cursorTop = 2;

     while (isEditing)
     {
         ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);

         // Обработка ввода
         switch (keyInfo.Key)
         {
             case ConsoleKey.E: // Ctrl+E - выход
                 if ((keyInfo.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0)
                 {
                     isEditing = false;
                     break;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     // Добавляем символ в текст
                     input += keyInfo.KeyChar;
                 }
                 break;

             case ConsoleKey.Backspace:
                 if (input.Length > 0)
                 {
                     // Удаляем последний символ из текста
                     input = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1);
                     Console.Write("\b \b"); // Удаляем символ с консоли
                 }
                 break;

             case ConsoleKey.Enter: // Enter - перейти на новую строку
                 input += "\n";
                 Console.WriteLine(); // Переход на новую строку в консоли
                 break;

             case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                 if (cursorLeft > 0)
                 {
                     cursorLeft--;
                     Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);
                 }
                 break;

             case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                 if (cursorLeft < input.Length)
                 {
                     cursorLeft++;
                     Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);
                 }
                 break;

             case ConsoleKey.PageUp:
                 if (cursorTop > 0)
                 {
                     cursorTop--;
                     Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);
                 }
                 break;

             case ConsoleKey.PageDown:
                 if (cursorTop < input.Split('\n').Length - 1)
                 {
                     cursorTop++;
                     Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);
                 }
                 break;

             default: // Добавить введенный текст
                 input += keyInfo.KeyChar;
                 Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar); // Отображаем введенный символ в консоли
                 break;
         }
     }

     return input;
 }

Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь!!

Судя по коду, отредактированный текст никак не сохранить, и если букву в слове пропустил, то её туда никак не вставить не переписав заново всю правую часть строки вручную. Вы уверены, что выбрали верный подход к реализации? Ведь если хотя-бы попытаться сохранить текст в файл, здесь сохранять попросту нечего и взять это негде.

вам нужно замутить собственный буфер строк, в нём и производить какие либо изменения, и когда вы будете перемещаться по консоли стрелками - то вы будете перемещаться по собственному буферу, и все изменения в буфере нужно будет единым фреймом перерисовывать (перевыводить) в консоль - это очень сильно упрощает ситуацию, тем более что вы отвязываетесь от внутреннего буфера консоли, потому что не знаете как он устроен [и никто не знает как он устроен]

далее, понятно что имея собственный буфер - вы этот буфер можете быстро подгрузить откуда либо и/или заполнить всем тем что вам нужно, и этот буфер теоретически не имеет пределов по размеру, а консоль - всего лишь "отображает в себя" маленькую часть вашего буфера [условные 25 строк], и все изменения во фрейме консоли - на самом деле это изменения в вашем буфере, который вы можете опять же куда либо выгрузить [почти] без проблем; суть в том что вы без своего буфера не обойдётесь, и в данном случае такой буфер называется "внешним", потому что существует собственный "внутренний" буфер консоли

скорость полной перерисовки фрейма [это по сути перевывод в консоль всех условных 25 строк] - зависит от длины этих строк, и в самом предельном [плохом] случае - это строки по стандартной ширине в 80 символов, т.е. фрейм - это 25x80, символов, и скорость перерисовки [перевывода 25 строк] - это от 1000-1500 фреймов в секунду, а вам такая скорость не нужна, т.е. понятное дело что при типичных 24фпсах - обновление фрейма много не съест, и конечно же собственный "внешний" буфер строк должен болтаться в другом потоке, и должен быть неблокирующимся

это для того, что бы всякое любое обращалось как либо к вашему же "внешнему буферу" без проблем, но тут нужен поток без блокировок, т.е. внешний буфер не должен иметь блокировок, вот тогда он будет не просто удобен, но и быстр

и когда вы будете двигаться в этом направлении всё дальше и дальше, то вы весьма быстро поймёте, что проще накарячить собственную консоль) а к этому всегда и приходят, в итоге появляется понятно работающая кучерявая консоль - и это неизбежно, если вы конечно же хотите заиметь вменяемую управляемую консоль, а мс-консоль вовсе не для того, что бы ею управляли "в широком смысле", она узко заточена под строго определённые операции, и как либо выходить за эти пределы - не следует, потому что от версии к версии мс-консолей - поведение вашей программки будет весьма сильно отличаться [вплоть до фейла]
